# Need help defining key-value pairs in json schema

Tags: arrays, json, object, jsonschema, key-value

I have a json which have the key : value pairs which trying to convert to JSON schema. How can I have the values dynamically for both key:value? [ i.e: test, testa, testb, testc, testd - needs to be dynamic ]

```
{"test" : {"content":{"testa" : "testb","testc" : "testd"}}}
```

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

1. Sample Json

   {"test" : {"content":{"testa" : "testb","testc" : "testd"}}}
2. I have converted the json to json schema with the help of below URL.
   https://codebeautify.org/json-to-json-schema-generator
3. Once it's converted copied and updated the json schema on Online Json editor to show the Editor view.

   https://json-editor.github.io/json-editor/?data=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
4. If you noticed in below Updated Form, Test, testa and testc are fixed values which I'm trying to have those as dynamic values.

   ```
   {
      "test": {
        "content": {
          "testa": "test",
          "testc": "test"
        }
      }
    }
   ```

I have tried converting the json to json schema but I'm unable to add the "key":"value" dynamically, instead of that key was getting fixed value.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the json schema you tried?

Comment: Please hehe a look at the [JSON Schema implementations page](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#from-data). There are a number of generators, both from code and from data.

Comment: I think it would help if you expanded on what you mean by `testa` being "dynamic."  You may have an easier time just hand-writing the schema.  Generators like this are not very reliable.

Comment: @gregsdennis testa is key in above example